# How to extend list in mysql with another list?

Tags: python, mysql, json

I have a list like this in a column: ["item 1", "item 2"]. I have a second list, ["item 3, "item 4"] and I want to extend the original list to get ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]. The original list is very long so I don't want to extract it, extend it, and then resend it. Using JSON_ARRAY_APPEND just gives me something like ["item 1", "item 2", "["item 3", "item 4"]"] which is not what I want.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Where is MySQL here?

Comment: You have no other choice but to overwrite the entire value in that row. You may not need to extract the value, but overwriting the contents is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE (‘[“item 1”, “item 2”]’, ‘[“item 3”, “item 4”]’);

will return:

[“item 1”, “item 2”, “item 3”, “item 4”]

FYI